# How to add single gradient color for two column <td>?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, linear-gradients

I have Two table columns data `<td>`, one is date and another is time. Now I want to add a gradient color, it starts from Date and ends with time like the below image. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5, Javascript, Jquery.

Is it possible to add gradient color or need to create a single column with Data and Time?

Any suggestion????

Refer image  [image]

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.date {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow);
}
.time {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow);
}
table
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Paper</th>
    <th>Pen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="date">21/1/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:13</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="date">22/2/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:23</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td class="date">3/3/2019</td>
    <td class="time">3:23</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First, post some code with an example of what you have tried so we can help to improve it. Second, maybe you can add the background gradient color to the `<tr>` row holding the `<td>` columns.

Comment: @Shidersz  Thanks for your reply. As per your idea adding a gradient to <tr> is not suitable here because there are so many table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the gradients in parts

```css
.a {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red 80%, white);
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  color: yellow;
}

.b {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red 80%, white);
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">Date</td>
    <td class="b">Time</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color:red
}
.date {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black, gray);
}
.time {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, gray, white);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
 
 </head>
 <body>

 <table>
   <tr>
  <th>Monthly Savings</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Paper</th>
  <th>Pen</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td class="date">21/1/2019</td>
  <td class="time">10:13</td>
   <td>white</td>
   <td>Black</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td class="date">22/2/2019</td>
   <td class="time">10:23</td>
  <td>Black</td>
  <td>white</td>
   
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>March</td>
  <td class="date">3/3/2019</td>
   <td class="time">3:23</td>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>red</td>
   
   </tr>
 </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Nice work. What about color starts with red and end with white. Is it possible for the percentage? for ex: Now we consider as a single table data column and over result should be 80%. Now the red-color fully covered the date column and then 80% coverd time column.  is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since your are setting a fixed with to your column, you can simply adjust the `background-size` to have the size of the both column and adjust the `background-position`. To be more accurate you need to also consider the `border-spacing` and the border (in your case you have `2px` border spacing and `4px` in total for borders)

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.date {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow) left/206px 100%;
}
.time {
  -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow) right/206px 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Paper</th>
    <th>Pen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="date">21/1/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:13</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="date">22/2/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:23</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td class="date">3/3/2019</td>
    <td class="time">3:23</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It will also work if you change the width of the columns, simply make sure the sum is respected:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.date {
  -webkit-column-width: 50px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 50px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow) left/126px 100%;
}
.time {
  -webkit-column-width: 70px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 70px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow) right/126px 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Paper</th>
    <th>Pen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="date">21/1/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:13</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="date">22/2/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:23</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td class="date">3/3/2019</td>
    <td class="time">3:23</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can easily change any color and adjust the color stop like you want:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.date {
  -webkit-column-width: 50px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 50px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 10%, green 20%,blue 50%,pink) left/126px 100%;
}
.time {
  -webkit-column-width: 70px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 70px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 10%, green 20%,blue 50%,pink) right/126px 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Paper</th>
    <th>Pen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="date">21/1/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:13</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="date">22/2/2019</td>
    <td class="time">10:23</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td class="date">3/3/2019</td>
    <td class="time">3:23</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```